# NavigationLink With Custom Data

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

As a new SwiftUI Student. I'm creating a workout tracker app where you can add your `Program`,`Routine` and `Exercises`:

My data relationship between `Exercise` and `Rotuine` will be *Many To Many* because an `Bench Press` could be related to many `Routines` and many Routines could have inside a `Bench Press`. Then there's the relationship between `Program` and `Routine` as *One To Many* due to a Routine could be related only to `Program`, but a `Program` could have a lot of `Routines` inside.

So my question is.

How can I relate a `Routine` to a `Program` if my 1st step is to create my `Program`, then with a navigation link I should go "inside" my `Program` where a can see or add my Rotuines?

Here's my code of `Programs` View:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ProgramsView: View {

@Query(sort: \Program.dateAdded, order: .reverse) private var allPrograms: [Program]

@State private var addPorgram: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List {
            ForEach(allPrograms) { allProgram in
                NavigationLink(value: allProgram) {
                    Label(allProgram.programName, systemImage: "folder")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Workout")
        .overlay {
            if allPrograms.isEmpty {
                ContentUnavailableView {
                    Label("No Programs Found", systemImage: "gym.bag.fill")
                }
            }
        }
        // Add New Program Button
        .toolbar{
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                Button {
                    addPorgram.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                        .font(.title3)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $addPorgram) {
        AddProgramView()
    }
  } 
}
```

And here's is data model for `Exercise`, `Routine` and `Program`:

```
@Model
class Exercise {
  //Exercise properties
  var exerciseName: String
  var category: String
  var weight: Int
  var dateLogged: Date
  var programs: Program?

init(exerciseName: String, category: String, weight: Int, dateLogged: Date,        programs: Program? = nil) {
    self.exerciseName = exerciseName
    self.category = category
    self.weight = weight
    self.dateLogged = dateLogged
    self.programs = programs
}


@Model
class Routine {
  var routineName: String
  var program: [Program]?
  var exercises: [Exercise]?

init(routineName: String, program: [Program]? = nil, exercises: [Exercise]? = nil)         {
    self.routineName = routineName
    self.program = program
    self.exercises = exercises
    }
  }


@Model
class Program {
  var programName: String
  var dateAdded: Date

init(programName: String, dateAdded: Date) {
    self.programName = programName
    self.dateAdded = dateAdded
  }

 }
```

Comment: Your textual description doesn’t match your code, a Routine has a one-to-many relationship to Routine even though you say the opposite. Also there is no Routine (or Exercise ) property in Program which there should be. So sort out the relationships and make sure that for each relationship a property exists for both ends.